# Is remix JS VM environment the same as local environment for solidity development?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I'm a bit lost on this spent a few hours on this but I cannot find out why, basically I have this Solidity contract (day 3 of luring blockchain). the code works in remix JS VM environment but when I try and build local and run it in ganache-cli with web3 it will deploy the first factory contract but it will not use the factory createFund function to make the second contract. is there something different form remix JS VM environment to a local one. or am I just missing something because I'm still new to this?

below is the code I'm playing with.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract testFactory{
    address[] public deployedFund;

    function createFund(string NewCampaignName) public{
       address newFund = new testFund(NewCampaignName, msg.sender);
       deployedFund.push(newFund);
    }

    function getDeployedFund() public view returns (address[]){
        return deployedFund;
    }
}

contract testFund {    
    struct OurFunders{
        string FristName;
        address ETHaddress;
        uint128 Amount;
        string Email;
        uint8 Funderpercent;
    }

    OurFunders[] public ourFunders;
    address public manager;
    uint8 public Fpercent;
    bool public IsFunded;
    string public CampaignName;    

     constructor (string NewCampaignName, address creater) public{
        manager = creater;
        CampaignName = NewCampaignName;
    }

    function newFunder(string FristName, address ETHaddress, uint128 Amount, string Email, uint8 Funderpercent) public{
        OurFunders memory newPerson = OurFunders({
            FristName: FristName, 
            ETHaddress: ETHaddress, 
            Amount: Amount, 
            Email: Email, 
            Funderpercent: Funderpercent
        });

        Fpercent = Fpercent + Funderpercent;

        if(Fpercent == 100){
            IsFunded = true;
        }

        ourFunders.push(newPerson);
    }
}
```

Comment: "...but it will not use use the factory `createFund`...". This doesn't make sense. How are you calling `createFund` after deploying `testFactory`?

Comment: right now I'm still just using moca to run testing on it what im doing is this 
" await compiledCampaign.methods.createFund("Test MN 1")
    .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: '2000000' });"
and then just running an assert on it to see if it has an address

Comment: Edit your question to add the test script. Your problem is likely in there.

Comment: working fine here seems something is wrong with your test add the scripts